# Run-time error '3706'. Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed"

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

i am getting error "Run-time error '3706'. The provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed" while running the VB code.

```
cn.Open ( _
"User ID=" & _
"; Password=" & _
"; Data Source=" & _
"; Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
```

I have a 64-bit Oracle client in my system window 10 and excel is 32bit.Could anyone tell me any possible solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I see that your code is having placeholders for `User ID` , `Password`, and `Data Source`, but your code is not assigning any values to these parameters. Did you forget to fill them in?

Comment: no ..here I have removed for security reason..in my actual code, I have everything @ahmad

Comment: So I take it this vb code is a macro in your 32-bit Excel? (Else, why even mention excel?).  I believe you'll need the 32-bit oracle client in this case.  The bit architecture of the oracle client needs to match that of the calling program.

Comment: Yes, the macro is in 32-bit excel,.so I need to deinstall the 64-bit oracle client and then need to install a 32-bit client ..right?..is there a way to have both 32 and 64-bit client in the same system and both works fine for respective applications? @EdStevens

Comment: Sure, at my company we install both 32-bit and 64-bit clients as a matter of course.  Just be sure to install into its own home, and name it so that you can identify the 32-bit and 64-bit homes.  something like 'c:\app\oracle\product\18.0.0\client_32' and 'c:\app\oracle\product\18.0.0\client_64'. Choose one to hold your tnsnames.ora, and set TNS_ADMIN as a system variable - TNS_ADMIN=C:\app\product\18.0.0\client_64\network\admin'